# Perda de pixels em input de um form e noutro não

Tags: css, css3

Tenho o seguinte `input`

```
<label class="labelPequeno">Endereço</label>
<input type="text" class="typeTextGrande" 
required maxlength="400" id="endereco" name="endereco" />
```

Com `class="typeTextGrande"`

`CSS`

```
.typeTextGrande, .typeTextMedio, .typeTextPequeno {
    height: 36px;
    padding: 4px;
}
.typeTextPequeno {
    width: 100px;
}
.typeTextMedio {
    width: 200px;
}
.typeTextGrande {
    width: 550px;
}
label {
    height: 40px;
    line-height: 40px;
    display: inline-block;
    vertical-align: middle;
}
.labelPequeno {
    width: 100px;
}
.labelMedio {
    width: 200px;
}
.labelGrande {
    width: 300px;
}
```

Ocorre que esse `input` é parte de um formulário de cadastro de clientes que existe tanto no `ambiente administrativo` quanto no `ambiente do cliente`. E, quando eu "Inspeciono" o elemento nos dois formulários eu noto que no ambiente do administrativo existe alguma perda `exatamente` de `12px` tanto no `width` quanto no `height` de todos os elementos.

Porém, não acho esses `12px`.

Comment: Adicione um link para a pagina caso o contrario ficara dificil ajudar.

Comment: ainda esta offline. Mas é o seguinte: Bo ambiente normal, o width e o height estão sendo respeitados. Mas no admin, o mesmo css, está tirando 12px tanto no width quanto no hight. Os códigos estão acima